# keep checkbox enabled using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox on my website which is currently enabled and it can be disabled by users. What I want to do is to keep it locked in that way so it cannot be disabled.

I think this can be achieved using jquery or javascript but I'm not quite sure how.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="check" id="moove_gdpr_strict_cookies">
```

And please note it's a wordpress website. So I can't edit HTML.

Comment: Just use this in document ready - `$('#moove_gdpr_strict_cookies').prop('disabled', true)`. It will disable the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple prevent click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#moove_gdpr_strict_cookies').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can return false `onclick` event

```
$('#moove_gdpr_strict_cookies').on('click',function(){
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to do something like this:

```
  var form = document.getElementById('yourform');
  form.onSubmit = function () { 
    var formElems = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0; i , formElems.length; i++){  
      if (formElems[i].type == 'checkbox'){ 
        formElems[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this. As suggested by the id of checkbox this checkbox has to do with GDPR. A user on your sight MUST have the right to decline cookies for tracking purposes (which this seems to be). Please be careful, as fines can be very high.

Technically most answers seem viable.